# php mysql order by priority and ranking

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table :

```
 Properties
 id     agency_id     refno
 1       1            AA101
 2       3            AA201
 3       2            AA501
 4       1            AA762
 5       3            AA555

 agency
 agency_id      agency_name     priority
  1                A              30
  2                B              10
  3                C              20
```

I have defined the priority of each agency in the agency table:

Now I want to extract the rows from properties table based on the ranking and priority. I want to extract 1st row from 1st agency, 1st row from 2nd agency, 1st row from 3rd agency and so on.

Then 2nd row from 1st agency, 2nd row from 2nd agency, 2nd row from 3rd agency and so on.

Then I want to sort the whole result based on the priority of each agency. I am using the following clauses but its not giving the desired result

```
 select properties.id,
        properties.agency_id,
        IF(@prev <> properties.agency_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := properties.agency_id,
        properties.refno
 where properties.agency_id = agency.agency_id
        order by agency.priority, rank
```

i have put the join, and its working fine there is no error. but i need the results as follow:

i have defined the priority of each agency in the agency table. the query is working fine with join. i need the results as follow:

```
 agency2 row1
 agency3 row1
 agency1 row1

 agency2 row2
 agency3 row2
 agency1 row2

 agency2 row3
 agency3 row3
 agency1 row3
```

according to the priority defined in the agency table and rank.

Comment: How do you assign the priority to each property?  Remember that SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there needs to be a column that explicitly contains this information.

Comment: Can you provide a table of what you would want the result to look like ideally? I'm not sure I understand the question...

Comment: You are missing the `FROM` clause, add it and use `JOIN` instead and [it will run](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ea24e/8) But not sure if this is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: i have defined the priority of each agency in the agency table. the query is working fine with join. i need the results as follow:

     agency2 row1
     agency3 row1
     agency1 row1

     agency2 row1
     agency3 row1
     agency1 row1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the concpet of a `JOIN`

The query must `join` the two tables.

```
select 
  properties.id,
  properties.agency_id,
  IF(@prev <> properties.agency_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, 
  @prev := properties.agency_id,
  properties.refno
FROM properties
INNER JOIN agency  ON properties.agency_id = agency.agency_id
order by agency.priority, rank
```

Comment: i have used the join, but still its not showing the desire results. the order should be as follow

     agency2 row1
     agency3 row1
     agency1 row1

     agency2 row2
     agency3 row2
     agency1 row2

     agency2 row3
     agency3 row3
     agency1 row3

and so on






agency

Comment: try `group by agency id`

Comment: group by shows only one row from each agency. i want to show all rows from each group till the end.

Comment: its working fine. i want to rank the latest properties according to the agency. i have a column name 'created' i am trying order by agency.priority, rank, properties.created, but its not giving me the desire result. how can i achieve it ????

Thank You

Comment: how can i rank the latest add properties for each agency ???? please help. i have a date field and i am trying to use it order by create desc. but its not working. 

Please help